# Getting systemd-journald (219) to listen somewhere other than /dev/log

Tags: logging, systemd, syslog, socket

I would like systemd-journald in systemd 219 (on el7, so the package is systemd-219-30.el7_3.9.x86_64) to listen for syslog messages on `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`, and have `/dev/log` be a *symlink* to that file.  This is the default behavior of more recent versions of systemd-journald.

The stock `/lib/systemd/system/sytemd-journald.socket` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Journal Socket
Documentation=man:systemd-journald.service(8) man:journald.conf(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sockets.target

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/systemd/journal/stdout
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/socket
ListenDatagram=/dev/log
SocketMode=0666
PassCredentials=yes
PassSecurity=yes
ReceiveBuffer=8M
```

I modify that file to remove the `ListenDatagram=/dev/log` line.

I created a new unit, `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journal-dev-log.socket` that looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Journal Socket (/dev/log)
Documentation=man:systemd-journald.service(8) man:journald.conf(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sockets.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

[Socket]
Service=systemd-journald.service
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
Symlinks=/dev/log
SocketMode=0666
PassCredentials=yes
PassSecurity=yes

ReceiveBuffer=8M
SendBuffer=8M

[Install]
WantedBy=systemd-journald.service
```

I modified `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service` so that it includes:

```
Sockets=systemd-journald.socket systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
```

I reload systemd (`systemctl daemon-reload`), enable the new socket `systemctl enable systemd-journald-dev-log.socket`) and restart all journald related units (`systemctl restart systemd-journald\*`), after which `systemctl cat systemd-journald.socket` shows that the changes are active:

```
# systemctl list-units | grep journald
systemd-journald.service               loaded active running   Journal Service
systemd-journald-dev-log.socket        loaded active running   Journal Socket (/dev/log)
systemd-journald.socket                loaded active running   Journal Socket

# systemctl cat systemd-journald.service | grep Socket
Sockets=systemd-journald.socket systemd-journald-dev-log.socket

# systemctl cat systemd-journald.socket | grep Listen
ListenStream=/run/systemd/journal/stdout
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/socket

# systemctl cat systemd-journald-dev-log.socket | grep Listen
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
```

But despite the above configuration, I find that `/dev/log` is not a symlink:

```
# ls -l /dev/log
srw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 0 Sep 12 17:33 /dev/log
```

And in fact it has been opened by `systemd-journald` directly, rather than by `systemd` itself:

```
# lsof | grep /dev/log
systemd-j 186     root    5u     unix 0xffff8b5076bc8000      0t0    157285 /dev/log
```

What's going on here? Why doesn't my socket unit work as expected? Is there any way to work around this problem that doesn't involve an upgrade to systemd?